# Apache custom error page (ssl_connection_error)

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

How to configure Apache to require client certificate based authentication on a specific direction? (httpd.conf  tags)

I've successfully configured Apache to require client certificate based authentication in specific location, but I still wont get it working in specific direction.

I need to do this to make a rewrite rule for custom error page when ssl connection error occures.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by in a specific direction.  Do you mean that clients have to have client certificates?

Comment: exactly that.. I'm making smartcard authentication. And when client don't have this required certificate/smartcard, the browser shows unwanted error page... don't know how to avoid that..

Answer (score 2):

You can't create a custom error page for "ssl connection error" because, if this happens, then there is no connection! The browser could not even send an HTTP request for the server to respond to, if SSL/TLS negotiation fails. The browser's built-in message is the only thing you will get. Fortunately, when this happens because of a missing or invalid client certificate, the browser's message will state this.

Comment: I was thinking of trying to do client authentication like this "optional still means require certificate authentication", as described here : http://ryandlane.com/blog/2010/07/29/requiring-ssl-client-authentication-in-a-user-friendly-way-in-apache/ Then there probably wold not be ssl_error.. page and perhaps I could make an custom error page there if I could to this for specific <Directory> location in httpd.conf..?