Client certificates and custom revoked html
I can configure Apache to authenticate users with client certificate and validate them via OCSP. Do you know how can I redirect the user to a custom html page if the certificate is revoked? The maximum I have achieved is getting a SSL error, which work fine but it is not user friendly.
I was thinking with SSLVerifyClient optional_no_ca and rewrite rules, but I don't know exactly how to do it.
Thanks.

Is this question related ? https://serverfault.com/questions/564180/apache-custom-error-page-ssl-connection-error I wonder as the SSL error is often displayed on the browser's own ssl error page.

You cannot do this as long as Apache is doing the validation and abandons the TLS handshake. Does this answer your question? Apache custom error page (ssl_connection_error)

ErrorDocument 401 or 403 should deal with those IIRC.
